# Infinite groups with all elements of order 2?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> **If G is a group such that $a^2 =e$ for all $a \in G$, where $e$ is the identity element in $G$, then $G$ is finite.**

This question can be proved false if we can get a group of infinite order with each non-identity element of order 2.

I thought of Klien's-4 group (order of each element=2) & Group of n-th root of unity (order of each element=n). But neither example works here.

Please help me in finding the counterexample for the above statement.

Comment: Hint: polynomials.

Comment: By the way, you meant to say that the order of each *non-identity* element is $2$. ;)

Comment: @fkraiem:i'meant for the order of all elements of G

Comment: @PKStyles well, such a group does not exist since the order of identity is always $1$ :)

Comment: @Levent:thanks! for pointing this,i misread the statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend the idea of the Klein-$4$ group:

$$\bigoplus^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}_2$$

Answer (score 6):

Let $S$ be a set. Then the power set $\mathcal P(S)$ is a group (with symmetric set difference as operation).

Answer (score 4):

More elementarily, the (additive) group of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbf{F}_2$. Or equivalently in computing terms, the group of finite binary strings with the bitwise XOR operation, where in order to "add" two strings of different lengths, the shorter one is zero-padded.

Answer (score 2):

**For example**:

The product of infinitely many copies of the cyclic group of order $2$
$$C_{2}^{\omega}=C_2\times C_2\times\dots $$